# if M1 and M2 are homeomorphic and M2 and M3 are homeomorphic then prove M1 and M3 are homeomorphic

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

if M1 and M2 are homeomorphic and M2 and M3 are homeomorphic prive M1 and M3 are homeomorphic.
M1 and M2 are homeomorphic, hence there exists a function f:M1 to M2 s.t f and its inverse both are continuous.
can I conclude the same function f is homeomorphism for M2 and M3? to show M1 and M3 are homeomorphic?

Answer (score 2):

No.  Let $g:M_2 \rightarrow M_3$ be a bicontinuous bijection.

Now what can you say about $g \circ f$?